# How To: Modify jquery.autocomplete regex to show results that starts with the given input

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I dont know enough to modify following code that will show me the word **starting** with the inputted characters.For eg.: If I type E or e it shows me **"Electrical,Electronics,Mechanical"** but I want only **"Electrical,Electronics"** to be displayed.How to do this?

I am using [jquery autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-disabled) plugin.

```
source: function(request, response) {
        var matcher = new RegExp($.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
        response(select.children("option").map(function() {

         var text = $(this).text();
         if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
             return {
             label: text.replace(
                 new RegExp(
                 "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                     $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                     ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                 ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
             value: text,
             option: this
            };
      }));
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In Javascript RegExp, `^` means *`startsWith`*:

```
var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
```

Comment: @Saurabh The 'i' parameter means that the regular expression will ignore case. In other words, the search will not be case sensitive, so, if you type 'm' lowercase, it still will return 'Mechanical' as a result.

Comment: Thanks a lot falsarella,it is working exactly as I wanted...thank you very much...