# How To: Modify struts2 jquery.autocomplete-plugin (jgeppert) to show results that starts with the given input

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, struts2

ist it possible to get only results BEGINNING with a given letter, not just CONTAINING it? For example if I enter "a" I only want to get results beginning with "a", e.g. "ape", "alien" etc., but not e.g. "banana". I DON'T want to get EVERY word containing the letter 'a'!

I'm using the autocompleter-Plugin from jgeppert (maven groupId: com.jgeppert.struts2.jquery) and the Tag

```
<sj:autocompleter name="city" id="selectCity" list="cities" listValue="name" listKey="id" onSelectTopics="autocompleteSelect" />
```

Which inserts an input field. I get the values from a List-Object which contains City-Objects. Each object has an id and a name.

Usually, if you're not using the struts2-Plugin but the jquery-autocompleter-Plugin, you can do it with

```
$('#element').autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        var matcher = new RegExp("^" + $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term), "i");
        response(select.children("option").map(function() {

         var text = $(this).text();
         if (this.value && (!request.term || matcher.test(text)))
             return {
                 label: text.replace(
                     new RegExp(
                     "(?![^&;]+;)(?!<[^<>]*)(" +
                         $.ui.autocomplete.escapeRegex(request.term) +
                         ")(?![^<>]*>)(?![^&;]+;)", "gi"
                     ), "<strong>$1</strong>"),
                 value: text,
                 option: this
            };
      }));
});
```

Got it from this Thread: [How To: Modify jquery.autocomplete regex to show results that starts with the given input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8520323/how-to-modify-jquery-autocomplete-regex-to-show-results-that-starts-with-the-gi)

But with the struts2-Plugin the JavaScript-Code is automatically generated and I don't know if I can use the above example!

Does anyone know how to modify the struts2-Plugin that way?